# How can I scrape data from iframe tag and widget class?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

Hi am trying to scrape data from iframe tag, inside this tag have widget-loader.I tried to scrape rating and reviews by using scrapy and selenium but I can't able to scrape information.

HTML:

```
\<div class="tp-widget-summary__rating"\>\<span class="rating"\>2.3\</span\> / 5 

\<span class="separator"\>•\</span\> 

\<span class="tp-widget-summary__count"\>\<strong\>3\</strong\> reviews\</span\>\</div\>
```

Python code:

```
self.driver.get(url) 

page_source = response.replace(body=self.driver.page_source) 

page_source.css(".tp-widget-summary__rating span::text").extract_first()
```

I also tried with simple scrapy code and other ways like xpath.

Expected: {'rating':2.3,'reviews':3}

Answer (score 0):

As the element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447).
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://shop.resmed.com.au/dreampad-pillow/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#trustpilotReviewsWidget iframe[title='Customer reviews powered by Trustpilot']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tp-widget-summary__information div.tp-widget-summary__rating > span.rating"))).text)
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tp-widget-summary__information div.tp-widget-summary__rating > span.tp-widget-summary__count > strong"))).text)
    ```
  - Console output:

    ```
    2.3
    3
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```